# Adapting Debian Sarge installation instructions (sources list) for Debian Squeeze?

Tags: linux, debian, load-balancing

I'm pretty new to sysadmin, and I'm trying to install the [UltraMonkey](http://www.ultramonkey.org/3/installation-debian.sarge.html) load-balancer on Debian 6.0 - Squeeze.

The installation instructions for Debian Sarge say to edit `sources.list`:

```
deb http://www.ultramonkey.org/download/3/ sarge main
deb-src http://www.ultramonkey.org/download/3 sarge main
```

I tried this, but when I do `apt-get install ultramonkey` I get `Unable to locate package ultramonkey`.

I then tried editing the sources to:

```
deb http://www.ultramonkey.org/download/3/ squeeze main
deb-src http://www.ultramonkey.org/download/3 squeeze main
```

But still the same issue.

Does anyone know how to adapt this for Squeeze, or is the answer basically 'You can't install UltraMonkey on Squeeze'?

Comment: A general remark only partially related to my answer: Did you issue an `apt-get update` command after editing `sources.list`? If not, apt doesn't even know about the packages from the additional repositories.

Comment: I hadn't, thanks for checking :) But I just tried it with the squeeze version of the source and got W: Failed to fetch `http://www.ultramonkey.org/download/3/dists/squeeze/main/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found`. Then I tried editing it back to sarge, running `apt-get update` again, and got a slightly different error: `GPG error: http://www.ultramonkey.org sarge Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY XXXXX`. Do I need to do something with my public key?

Answer (score 1):

Debian Sarge was 3.1, after that came 4, 5 and now 6. You shouldn't even try installing such an old package to a new system (and it's highly likely it won't work at all).

Generally, I would consider a project which has its last release in 2007 as dead and look for other alternatives.

If you insist, you will have to install it from the source code, but this is likely quite involved and nothing for a beginner.

Comment: You mean 2005. But you are absolutely right to go an alternative route.